# Selenium: Select child element with no parameters

Tags: java, html, selenium

due to the fact i'm using selenium for the first time i have a questin on selecting a child element without parameters.
I'm trying to get the child-div "element to be clicked" to perform a click.

Java:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("parent"));
WebElement element2 = element.findElement(By.xpath("/div/div/div")); // should be wrong
element2.click();
```

Given HTML-Code:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>element to be clicked</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
element.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='element to be clicked']"));
```

With RegEx

```
element.findElement(By.xpath("//div[matches(text(),'RegExExpression']"));
```

Comment: Can i use RegEX in text() like '\*element to be clicked\*' ?

Comment: @hehe: You can use regex with `matches` function

Comment: i accept your answer as the better answer because its more elegant, but @Nadun's answer also works

Answer (score 0):

While there's nothing to identify directly, we can do something like this..

```
List<WebElement> divs = driver.findElements(By.tagname("div")); //This will return all div elements
```

Then we can try something unique to that div..

```
for(int i = 0; i < divs.size(); i++) {
     if(divs.get(i).getText().equals("element to be clicked")) {
         divs.get(i).click();
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to iterate from a given tag like here "parent"?